# *** caught segfault ***; address 0x5573328516d8, cause 'memory not mapped' in R shiny (golem) app deployed via shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, segmentation-fault, window, golem

I have got a problem with my R Shiny app which runs perfectly fine locally but irregularly returns "Disconnected from the server: Reload" when deployed via shinyapps.io. **Note** that users do not get disconnected every time they click the "Create/update graph!"-Button, but instead (strangely enough) only irregularly.

For reference, here are the logged messages that I focused on:

```
2021-07-13T12:24:26.495243+00:00 shinyapps[4159264]:  *** caught segfault ***
2021-07-13T12:24:26.495244+00:00 shinyapps[4159264]: address 0x5573328516d8, cause 'memory not mapped'
```

Followed by a traceback starting with:
**`2021-07-13T12:24:26.497790+00:00 shinyapps[4159264]: 1: policy %in% input$recycling_option_choice_checkbox`**
and ending in:

```
2021-07-13T12:24:56.324135+00:00 shinyapps[4159264]: 91: local({    if (identical(.Platform$OS.type, "unix")) {        whoami <- system("whoami", intern = TRUE)        if (identical(whoami, "root")) {            stop("Attempted to run application as whoami=", whoami,                "; USER=", Sys.getenv("USER"))        }    } ...
2021-07-13T12:24:56.324136+00:00 shinyapps[4159264]: An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
```

Since the app is built in a golem framework, I am not able to provide a minimal/reproducible example. The following lines of code are intended to give you an idea of how the module is structured. Note also that users only get disconnected from time to time when clicking the "Create/update graph!"-Button in a module where subsetting the data used for subsequent plots is subsetted using checkboxGroupInput(). For other moduls with selectInput() instead of checkboxGroupInput(), the app does not only work locally but also on the shinyapps.io-server.

#### Module

##### UI

```
mod_plotting_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)

# Infobox showing by a text and a color whether graph has to be created for the first time (blue), is up to date (green) or has to be updated (red)
shinydashboard::infoBoxOutput(ns("informationbox1"), width = 12)

# Action button for the graph
actionButton(ns("go"), "Create/update graph!", icon = icon("arrow-down"))

# checkboxGroupInput (with bsButton for additional info on specific options)
sidebarPanel(
            tags$style(HTML('#bsButton_recycling_option_choice_checkbox {margin-top: 30px}')),
            fluidRow(
              column(10,
                     tags$div(
                       checkboxGroupInput(ns("recycling_option_choice_checkbox"), "Choose recycling options:",
                                          c("Option 1" = "Option 1",
                                            "Option 2" = "Option 2"
                                            "Option 3" = "Option 3",
                                            "Option 4" = "Option 4",
                                            "Option 5" = "Option 5"),
                                          selected = c("Option 1"))
                     )
              ),
              column(2, 
                     shinyBS::bsButton(ns("bsButton_recycling_option_choice_checkbox"))
              )
            )
          )

# Description belonging to the previous bsButton
shinyBS::bsPopover(id = ns("bsButton_recycling_option_choice_checkbox"), title = HTML(paste("<strong>Description</strong>")),
                         content = HTML("..."),
                         placement = "right", 
                         trigger = "focus",  options = list(container = "body"))

}
```

##### Server

```
mod_plotting_server <- function(input, output, session, type, parent){
  ns <- session$ns

# Initiate the status
status <- shiny::reactiveVal()

# Initially (empty/grey) graph
r <- shiny::reactiveVal(    
    plot = ggplot(dataframe)
  )
  
# Status after clicking the actionButton (i.e. after creating a graph for the first time or after updating a graph)
out <- eventReactive( input$go , {
    status("Well done. Graph is up to date!")
    paste("")
  })

# Subsetting and plotting
observeEvent( input$go , {
        # Subsetting
        dataframe_subset<- dataframe %>% 
          dplyr::filter(    
            policy %in% input$recycling_option_choice_checkbox               # this seems to be the source of the problem
          )
        # Plotting
        r$plot <- ggplot(data = dataframe_subset, ...) 
})

# Status at beginning and status when graph needs to be updated
observeEvent({list(input$recycling_option_choice_checkbox)},
               ifelse(getCount(input$go) == 0,       #1) getCount(): function returning number of clicks on actionButton (see below) 
                      {status("Create first graph by clicking the 'Create/update graph!'-Button!")},
                      {status("Please update the graph according to your changed inputs by clicking the 'Create/update graph!'-Button!")})
               )
               
# Maximum and minimum options that can be chosen in checkbox
observe({
    # Max 3
    if(length(input$recycling_option_choice_checkbox) > 3) {
      showNotification("You cannot choose more than 3 recycling options at a time.",
                       duration = 8, type = "message", closeButton = FALSE)
    }
    # Min 1
    if(getCount(input$go) >= 1 & length(input$recycling_option_choice_checkbox) < 1) {
      showNotification("You need to choose at least one recycling option.",
                       duration = 8, type = "message", closeButton = FALSE)
    }
  })
  
# Reaction if maximum or minimum is reached
observe({
    if(length(input$recycling_option_choice_checkbox) > 3){
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "recycling_option_choice_checkbox", selected = tail(input$recycling_option_choice_checkbox, 3))
    }
    if(length(input$recycling_option_choice_checkbox) < 1){
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "recycling_option_choice_checkbox", selected = "Option 1")
    }
  })

# Actual information box showing by a text and a color whether graph has to be created for the first time (blue), is up to date (green) or has to be updated (red)
output$informationbox1 <- shinydashboard::renderInfoBox({
    shinydashboard::infoBox(
      title = "",
      value = tags$div(style = "line-height: 1.4;",
                       tags$h5(renderText({out()}),
                               renderText({status()}))),
      icon = icon("exclamation-circle"),
      color = getColor(status(), input$go),      #2) getColor(): function returning a specific color (see below)
      fill = TRUE
    )
  })

# Show graph
output$plot <- renderPlot({
    r$plot
  })
  
}
```

### Functions defined outside of the module

```
# 1)
getColor <-  function(placeholder, counts) {
  place <- placeholder
  count <- 0 + counts
  if(count == 0)
  {return('light-blue')}
  else if(count != 0 & place  == "Well done. Graph is up to date!")
  {return('olive')}
  else return('red')
}
# 2)
getCount <-  function(counts) {
  count <- 0 + counts
  if(count == 0)
  {return(0)}
  else return("more than 0")
}
```

Any help appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Maxl

Comment: What happens if you deploy it on a local shiny server? Does it work? Perhaps there's a resource limiting (guessing here), like memory?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: Thanks for your guess. I haven't tried this because I have so far not set up a local shiny server.

Answer (score 1):

It means there's a (rather serious) bug in at least one of the libraries that you are using. If this is not windows, you could try running it with valgrind (initialize with something like `valgrind R` in a terminal and run the shiny app from there) - that should tell you which specific package is causing the crash. Perhaps if you inspect the full error log it would say where specifically it is failing.

After that, you should report the bug to the package mantainer.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Since I am on Windows, which Valgrind substitute would you suggest?